# SPMetal Error : An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: sharepoint-server, linq

I am using the following command to generate entity class for Linq to SharePoint.

```
spmetal.exe /web:http://mywebname:port /code:D:\CustomerClass.cs
```

I am getting Error "An item with the same key has already been added"

I tried this command `stsadm -o reconvertallformtemplates`

but no success.

Please help me.